# How to create a pivot table with the lowest 80% of the source data values?

Tags: excel, average, pivot-table

I am having the following data:

```
PARAM    VALUE
p1       23
p1       11
p2       15
p1       37
p3       65
p1       12
...      ...
```

What I want is to create a pivot table, with the average VALUE per PARAM, but not from the full source data: I want the average to account only the 80% lowest VALUEs per PARAM.

For example:
if `p1` has the following values (sorted):

```
12
15
17
18
25
```

I want the average in the pivot table to take into account the first 80%, i.e. from `12` to `18`. This way I am trying to filter out peaks in the data series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution might not be very efficient but it gets the job done.

I am assuming you data starts from cell `A1`.

First i will comment on the strategy applied and then i will go into the steps one by one.

***Strategy***

- Pivot the data initially to get for each group the `VALUEs`
- Working on the pivot for each `PARAM` get the 80% `PERCENTILE`.
- Create a key in the initial data and compare each `VALUE` with the respective `PERCENTILE` of that `PARAM`. The pivot the new data set and you done.

***Steps***

1) `C1` cell write `Key`. In cell `C2` put the formula `=COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)` and copy down.

2) Pivot this table and have `PARAM` as `Column Labels`, `Key` as `Row Labels` and `VALUE` in `Σ values` like this: [image: Excel Spreadsheet]

3) In `G1` insert this formula to get the value at 80% `=PERCENTILE(G4:G20,0.8)` the `G20` depends on how many rows the pivot has.

4) In cell `D1` write `key1` and in cell `D2` insert the formula `=(B2<INDEX($G$1:$I$1,MATCH(A2,$G$3:$I$3,0)))*1` and copy down.

5) Finally pivot the new table and have a filter `key1` equal to `1`.

Comment: Thank you Dimitri for the solution, but, I do not think that PERCENTILE returns what I need: I need to average on the values of the first (lowest) 80% of the source values. Maybe I did not make this clear initially.

Comment: This is what i understood. You need `PERCENTILE` to identify for each `p1`, `p2` etc what is the value below which are the 80% of observations. Then with the new pivot and `key1=1` you filter on those and take the average of `VALUE` per `PARAM`